# Can I enforce the same variables across variable groups in the Azure DevOps Pipeline Library?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have several variable groups defined under Pipeline Library. I'm using a different group for each release environment (e.g., DEV, QA, PROD). The deployment for each environment needs all the same variables but with different values.

It's a long list of variables and I have no way to tell if my groups are getting out of sync with one another over time as we add and remove variables.

I really wish I had something like a C# interface to make all the groups match. I was hoping the new YAML templates could help somehow but I can't find anything that would solve this.

Anyone have a good solution to this? It seems like a very common use of variable groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I enforce the same variables across variable groups in the Azure
>   DevOps Pipeline Library?

No, we can't do that. It seems what you want is to sync the variable groups for **DEV,QA,PROD** environments, making these groups have same variable list but different values.

As I know this is **not supported** for now. [Variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) is originally designed to share variables **across pipelines** instead of other directions, so Azure Devops Service doesn't support such out-of-box feature to compare and sync variable groups.

**Update1:**

I submitted a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/1020605/an-option-to-sync-or-compare-variable-groups.html) in User Voice forum that you can vote and track.

**Update2:**

1.Another direction if you want to check the variable list easily: If you want to check the variable list manually, you can consider using [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get%20variable%20groups%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get a Json response of your variable list for one specific variable group.

2.There're many related topics about how to convert Json to CSV/Excel file online, and after my test it's quite convenient. So maybe you can get three josn response and then convert then into text file/excel file to compare the difference between these three variable lists. It could be a temporary workaround ~

Hope it helps :)